# Data tables suggestion?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datatables

I'm looking for a easy to use and flexible data table jquery plugin.
Any suggestions?

I found [datatables.net](http://datatables.net). Is there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like jqGrid best.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: In conjunction with jquery I never tried anything else. I worked with the tables from extJs, YUI and Qooxdoo and some exots from Telerik on the ASP.NET site. But with jquery I never had any wishes, jqgrid could not fulfil. I am sorry, that I can not make any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I integrated Data table for the data coming from the server seamlessly. Works well and has lot of features like multi column sorting, pagination, google like search etc. I have heard good things about jqGrid as well http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html Haven't tried it yet but will do so in near future.

Comment: +1 for DataTables plugin. It's the best. It has feature parity with jqGrid and has better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the ["Tables" category](http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/tables) on [plugins.jquery.com](http://plugins.jquery.com/)? It looks like they are plenty to choose from depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Slickgrid: http://jquerystyle.com/2010/09/02/slickgrid